# Android playing video with SurfaceView and android media player cause blocking UI

Tags: android, media-player, surfaceview

Hi I am developing android application in which I want to play video using URI as source. So my problem scenario is like this I have 2 activities. From one activity I am starting another activity in which I am playing my video. So problem is like this when I start my video player activity and If I click back before on prepare get execute It will close player activity but my previous activity is not responsive then. I check my log records it indicates that although it close my player activity; it's not going through on destroy. It will execute ondestroy after some delay. once on destroy for player activity got executed then only my activity become responsive. So my two activity life cycle logs looks like

```
inside on pause of activity A
inside on create of player activity
inside on surface change 
inside on destroy of of activity A
inside on create of activity A
inside on resume of activity A
inside on stop of player activity     // delay occured here ...
inside on destroy of player activity  // delay occured here ...
```

and my player code looks like this :

```
private class PeparePlayer extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> 
{    
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
         try {
             mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), targetUri);
             mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
             //mediaPlayer.prepare();    
         } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         } catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }

         mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.i("MJKMJKMJKMJKMJKMJKMJKMJK", "MJKMJKMJKMJKMJKMJKMJKMJK inside on prepare listener ");
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
            });
        return null;
    }

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}
}
```

once it execute on prepare and if then I click back then it works fine. But if I click back before onprepare completion it cause this UI blocking problem. Am I doing some thing wrong? Need Some help. Thank you.

Comment: You shouldn't need to wrap this in an async class, prepare async should be taking care of this as a background task. Try preparing it in the normal thread see what happens.

Comment: Thank you Brain for your replay. I tested on multiple devices and face this problem on only google devices like google nexus and tablet. On other devices its working fine. I don't know what is the problem with that. Trying to solve this problem since long time. If you know some thing regarding this issue please let me know to solve  this problem.